# Can I make website links in the desktop look like the favicons?

Tags: icons, url

I've just installed Ubuntu 16.04 and created all the links to websites that had been in my Windows 10 Desktop. I opened Firefox, surfed to each site and dragged and dropped the (i) in the address bar into the desktop. Now all links are there but they have no picture, just a "<" / ">" which is not so nice. Can I make the links show the websites favicons or screenshots I take or so?

Comment: I opened the .desktop file with gedit and put the path to a .png file after  Icon= and it works. Sorry, did not expect it it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Open the .desktop file for that link (e.g. Gmail.desktop) in the Desktop in a text editor and put /somepath/someimage.png after "Icon="